# How to design this relaional database

Tags: database

I want to question about relational database. I have two tabel , They are airport_tbl and complain_tbl. Primary key of airport_tbl is airport_id and their fields are airport_name and airport_location. In complain_tbl I want to make airport_departure and airport_arrival and they are foreign key of airplane_tbl. Is is possible? Or dou you have other idea for designing this database? I will appreciate if you can help me. Thanks

Comment: Foreign Key is a column or a combination of columns whose values match a Primary Key in a different table. So airport_departure and airport_arrival should be a primary key in another table.

Comment: is it possible if I make two foreign key from same primary key in airport_tbl?